# Turn off video stabilization for bebop drone

Tags: ros, bebop-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the purposes of my project, we want to read the live video feed of a parrot bebop 2 drone, but without any video stabilization running. I'm using ROS with the bebop_autonomy package to do so. However, the footage is automatically stabilized.

I tried adjusting the parameter `PictureSettingsVideoStabilizationModeMode` through rqt_reconfigure, but this seems to have no effect. Is there another parameter that needs to be adjusted, or is there something that I need to do before the change takes effect?

I'm using the latest version of the package, compiled from source (commit `d386d20`).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243339/turn-off-video-stabilization-for-bebop-drone/) by [TomRoussel](https://answers.ros.org/users/27938/tomroussel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-09**:
I feel like you may have a better chance at getting a good answer by reporting this to [AutonomyLab/bebop_autonomy/issues](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/bebop_autonomy/issues). If the dyn_recfg infra shows that option, then it should work. If not, that seems like a potential bug. So report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've update the driver to support SDK 3.10.x and firmware 3.9. I can confirm that you can now disable video stabilisation using dynamic reconfigure. The corresponding ROS parameter is [`~PictureSettingsVideoStabilizationModeMode`](http://bebop-autonomy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autogenerated/ardrone3_settings_param.html#picturesettingsvideostabilizationmodemode).

The code has been merged into [the main branch of `bebop_autonomy`](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/bebop_autonomy/commits/indigo-devel).

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2016-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0